# stubbing class inside controllers action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

Is it possible to stub a class inside controllers action?

I want to stub the `SomeServiceObject` to return falsey value for me to get to the `else` statement.

```rb
# controllers/users_controller.rb

...

def index
  service = SomeServiceObject.new(...)

  if service.perform
    render json: { code: 100 }
  else
    render json: { code: 200 } 
  end
end

...
```

I tried this one but no luck

```rb
# users_controller_spec.rb

...

allow(SomeServiceObject).to receive(:perform).and_return(false)

...
```

Comment: What are you returning from your service? why not handle errors within the service? i.e. instead of instantiating a new service object and checking whether `perform` succeeds or not in your controller, just call `perform` directly from your controller and return some object that tells you if it succeeded or not. Something like an `OpenStruct` would work. Doing this work in your controller seems like its negating the purpose of a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to do this would be via `instance_double`.

```
let(:some_service_object) { instance_double(SomeServiceObject) }

before do
  allow(SomeServiceObject).to receive(:new).and_return(some_service_object)
  allow(some_service_object).to receive(:perform).and_return(false)
end
```

Another way to go with this would be using `any_instance_of`:

```
allow_any_instance_of(SomeServiceObject).to receive(:perform).and_return(false)
```

However you might get warning that `any_instance` is deprecated and not recommended to use in test. You can read more on reasons for this here:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

and here:

> any_instance is the old way to stub or mock any instance of a class but carries > > the baggage of a global monkey patch on all classes.
>   Note that we generally recommend against using this feature

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance